# Serving Images from subdomain in wordpress

Tags: images, url-rewriting, uploads, options, media

This is my current image url

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/sample.png` served via cloudflare

`uploads` folder is in my wordpress installation

I am syncing the uploads folder to Backblaze B2 bucket and have cloudflare url `static.example.com` pointing to backblaze bucket and i  have url rewrite rule to access the image via `https://static.example.com/2022/06/sample.png`

Now i want to serve the images from `static.example.com` but want to keep managing the media via wordpress locally so i will have full copy both locally as well as backblaze B2 but all images will be served by backblaze B2.

I am not sure which setting i have to change in wordpress

The only reason i am making 2 copies is because wordpress keeps the good job of making multiple copies of images and nice media manager to select images

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch images (All types of media Items) that are hosted somewhere with a plugin [**External Media without Import**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-media-without-import/)

By using this plugin you don't require to upload media items to your wp site locally because you can fetch them directly from other sources. I used this app before and it's work excellent for me. Thank You